# Sorting file by the modification time

Tags: bash, sorting

I want to make a sorting with respect to the **modification times** using e.g bubblesort and to print every element of the arr[] using **stat -c %y %n filename**.

```
 #!/bin/sh

 arr=(*)  # * is list of all file and dir names

 newest=${arr[0]}
 for f in "${arr[@]}";
 do 
    if [ $f -nt $newest ]; then 
    newest=$f  
    fi 
 echo "$(stat -c %y %n $newest)"
 done
```

I want to take an output something like **ls -art --full-time** but of course this is more complete. My question is why it is not print the filename?Thanks a lot.

Comment: You say `stat -c %y %n filename` above but there's no `%n` in `stat -c %y $newest`.  Typo?

Comment: Yes, Sorry i forgot it. It is not working anyhow. And i am not sure for the position of the output "echo"

Comment: `echo` and `$()` are rough inverses (it'll collapse whitespace); do you really want that?  Just running `stat` directly might be more correct.  But my real point was to get you to look at your format string...

Answer (score 2):

The format string needs to be a single parameter; use quotes to accomplish this.  You probably don't want to use `echo $(stat ...)` there either, as I noted in the comments.

```
stat -c '%y %n' "$newest"
```

(Technically you should be doing more quoting, against the possibility of filenames with spaces in them.)